# Subtract Pixels From Percentage in SASS?

Tags: percentage, sass, pixel

I know you're able to do some simple math in Sass/Scss. But is there a way to subtract pixels from percentages? For example:

```
$image-size: 200px;

.bio {
    width: 100% - $image-size;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how that would even work, fact is SASS can't magically know the size your box will have.

Now if I get what you're trying to do, best solution would be to wrap .box's parent width into a variable and then substract your image width to that variable - considering 100% width means it will get 100% of a certain width.

Comment: `calc()` is the magic that sass was missing.  This answer is no longer correct.

Comment: @SethBattin To say that the answer is "no longer correct" is not entirely true:  Sass *cannot* subtract pixels from percentages/em/rem/vh/vw/etc.  `calc()` is a feature of CSS, not Sass.

Comment: @cimmanon It's an unhelpful distinction to make, to stress that sass cannot do a thing, when the the goal is to implement that thing in css.  Using sass is just an extra complexity to the styling, and Aperçu's answer deals with that complexity.

Comment: @SethBattin It *is* an important distinction to make, especially if the goal is to store the value into a variable for further calculations (not a requirement in the OP's case, but this question and its answers aren't just for the OP). I did not say that Aperçu's answer is incorrect, just that your statement is not entirely true or accurate.  I do agree, however, that this answer is *incomplete*

Answer (score 20):

You can use the **[calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** function to get what you want. It's experimental but still [pretty good supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) by the different browsers.

With *Sass*, you can create a `calc mixin` to get this working on more browser versions with the`-webkit` and `-moz` prefixes (no need of the *Opera* one):

```sass
@mixin calc($key, $value) {
  #{$key}: -webkit-calc(#{$value});
  #{$key}: -moz-calc(#{$value});
  #{$key}: calc(#{$value});
}
```

And call it with something like:

```sass
.bio {
  @include calc("width", "100% - #{$image-size}");
}
```